# Use maven filtering in server.xml without breaking mvn liberty:dev

Tags: websphere-liberty, liberty-maven-plugin

I would like to use [maven filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html), in my *src/main/liberty/config/server.xml* without breaking the use of *liberty:dev* from the *maven-liberty-plugin*.  My biggest problem seems to be that the *liberty-maven-plugin* does not honor filtering.

For example, consider this **webApplication** element:

```
<webApplication id="${project.artifactId}" contextRoot="/"
    location="${server.config.dir}/apps/${project.artifactId}.war">
</webApplication>
```

Without any other guidance, this file is copied to *target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/server.xml* without any filtering, so the runtime cannot find the WAR file.

Let's say I manually turn on the filtering using **maven-resources-plugin**:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>01-liberty-config</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer</outputDirectory>
        <resources>          
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/liberty/config</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
          </resource>
        </resources>              
      </configuration>            
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now the filtering works and the file is in the correct location.  Unfortunately, I observe that when I run **mvn liberty:dev**, this gets overwritten by the unfiltered *server.xml* from *src/main/liberty/config/server.xml*.

Is it possible to use maven filtering in a *server.xml*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### BACKGROUND

This is essentially not supported today.   The `liberty-maven-plugin` doesn't let you do this, and the way in which the `liberty-maven-plugin` manages and controls the Liberty config also doesn't make it easy for you to use standard Maven plugins like 'dependency' or 'resources' plugin either.

Since this [issue](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/587) was raised before I shared a [sample](https://github.com/scottkurz/lmp-issue-587) approach which you might find useful, though it has the feel of a workaround.

### SOLUTION OVERVIEW

Basically, although although we can't substitute into server.xml itself via filters we can substitute into a config snippet that gets included by server.xml, and copy this into place using the resources plugin, rather than `liberty-maven-plugin`.

### SOLUTION DETAIL

Say I wanted to use a "filter"-style Maven variable substitution `${tidal.url}` for a URL in Liberty server config.

#### 1. src/main/filtered-config/environment.xml

First define a config snippet, which we are going to apply the filter to.

```xml
<server description="environment">
    <!-- Expect to come from filter -->
    <variable name="tidal.url" value="${tidal.url}"/>
</server>
```

#### 2. pom.xml

Configure an execution of `resources:copy-resources` copying the "environment.xml" snippet above to the shared config dir location, **target/liberty/wlp/usr/shared/config**, with filtering enabled:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <!-- This location can persist across a server recreate, where the refresh can annoyingly wipe out your earlier copy -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/liberty/wlp/usr/shared/config</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/filtered-config</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

#### 3. server.xml

In your main server.xml config file, add an `<include>` of the config snippet you copied into the shared config dir via "copy-resources".

Also shown is how we finally use or "consume" the value applied via the filter, here in this `<jndiEntry>`, in this sample:

```xml
 <include location="${shared.config.dir}/environment.xml"/>

 <!-- This is how I'm ultimately going to "consume" the filtered value -->
 <jndiEntry jndiName="url/tidal-api" value="${tidal.url}" id="TidalJNDI" />
```

#### 4. Run dev mode, invoking the extra goal first, and activating your filter somehow

E.g.:

```sh
mvn resources:copy-resources liberty:dev
```

As far as activating your filter, maybe you have a filter defined in your build (via  build.filters.filter like in my sample repo) or maybe you're just using `-Dtidal.url=<value>`.

### FOLLOW-UP

Besides being complicated a significant limitation of the above is that you only get a single chance to apply the filter.   You cannot iterate through different values in a single dev mode "session".

Feel free to give feedback on the issue:  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/587

Also I will note we are considering enhancing filter support for general resources and web resources [here](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/1104).

### ONE MORE THOUGHT

If all you need is a dynamic way to select, at build time, one set of Liberty config values vs. another you don't necessarily need to use filtering.

You could instead use the [support](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/blob/main/docs/common-server-parameters.md#setting-liberty-configuration-with-maven-project-properties) which maps Maven properties to Liberty config.

E.g. for this example you could have one profile which defines

```xml
<properties>
    <liberty.var.tidal.url>URL1</liberty.var.tidal.url>
</properties>
```

and another profile defining the same property with a different value.

This would parameterize my sample:

```xml
<jndiEntry jndiName="url/tidal-api" value="${tidal.url}" id="TidalJNDI" />
```

just fine.

The problem though is if you wanted to use the same sets of properties in other contexts with other plugins that did fully support filtering.   Then, you want standard Maven filtering.

Comment: Hello Scott, I tried to apply this but may have found a regression. Please see https://github.com/OpenLiberty/ci.maven/issues/583#issuecomment-845532768 .